# Maven: No source to compile

Tags: maven, selenium, compilation, webdriver

I have converted old project into Maven, after run as Maven Test, it shows following warning:

[image]

Could someone please help me with solutions if any.

Thanks!

Comment: could you please share the logs and also the how you are "running as maven"

Comment: Well, do you have any tests? If so, are they in `src/test/java` ?

Comment: Also note that there are actual WARNINGs (about not having specified a source file encoding, which can break builds on other machines).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make changes in your project folder structure as well.
Maven expects files to be in the specific directories.

> Source files -> src/main/java
>
> Source resources -> src/main/resources
>
> Test files -> src/test/java
>
> Test resources -> src/test/resources

Restructure your project skeleton and run the maven again. Hope it works!